# Use my node.js application on my host

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sockets, websocket

I have created an example chat application using **node.js, mongodb, socket.io** but I have created it on my localhost and it works perfectly.

I have tried to upload it on my host server which is `Inmotionhosting`but It get me an error saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined` and `couldn't load socket.io/socket.io.js`

I just uploaded my chat application folder to the server is there any others steps to do?

Thanks

Comment: What did you get from `inmotionhosting`?  They provide dedicated servers, VPS and Web Hosting, which will give you distinct setups.  Your error says that `socket.io` is not installed, if you got a dedicated or a VPS you need to install it yourself (with `npm`).

Comment: no i use shared hosting

Comment: Give details of what you did: how did you upload the code? which exact service are you using? give a link to it.  You have no `socket.io` on whatever server you're using, whether that server should have it i a question of reading about the service you're using.  Have you read their [article about nodejs](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/getting-started-guides/nodejs)  (especially the part about shared hosting)?

Comment: I am using shared hosting and here is the link `www.trafficpets.com/chat`

Comment: You need to check if package.json is on your project directory on the hosting server. Regardless of the server type, and what you manage yourself, a node.js application must have  a "package.json" and run
    npm install